# How to read specific setting from Hive shell

Tags: hadoop, hive

So you can set a setting in the Hive console with:

```
hive> set hive.enforce.bucketing=true
```

And you can view ALL of the settings with:

```
hive> set
```

or

```
hive> set -v
```

But how do you **read the current value of a specified setting** from the Hive console?

```
hive> hive.enforce.bucketing;
NoViableAltException(26@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1074)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:202)
        ...
FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '.' 'enforce'
```

Right now I'm redirecting `hive -e 'set'` to file and then using `grep`.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `set` and the property name without a value

```
hive> set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize;
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=256000000
```